# Remove query string "?" in HTML form method GET

Tags: javascript, forms, query-string

I have a simple search form of Google Images that open in a new window. When I want to change the form parameters to Unsplash (that don't use query strings on their URL search) the form continue sending query string ;(

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="google" name="image" onclick="googleImages();" checked/>
<label for="google">Google Images</label>

<input type="radio" id="unsplash" name="image" onclick="unsplash();"/>
<label for="unsplash">Unsplash</label>

<form id="form" method="GET" action="https://www.google.com/search?q=">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="q" value="" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';">
    <input id="helper" type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
</form>
```

JS

```
var
  form = document.getElementById("form"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  helper = document.getElementById("helper");

function googleImages() {
  form.action="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
  input.name="q";
  helper.name="tbm";
  helper.value="isch";
}
function unsplash() {
  form.action="https://unsplash.com/search/photos/";
  input.name="";
  helper.name="";
  helper.value="";
}
```

How create a function that remove query string from output URL? (and set again parameters when a radio option need them)

- See code working here: http://jsbin.com/qitadepoxu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

So if you are not sending any parameters to unsplash.com don't use form submit. Instead use javascript redirect inside unsplash() function.

```
window.location.href = "https://unsplash.com/search/photos/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've clarified in a comment that when calling Unsplash, you need to pass the search string as part of the URL rather than as a query string parameter, like this: `https://unsplash.com/search/photos/lion`

To do that with your current setup, you'll need to do two things:

1. Add the string to the URL, and
2. *Disable* the form fields. Disabled form fields aren't sent with the form at all; [link to spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#constructing-form-data-set). (Alternately, of course, you could *remove* them, but if you change your form at some point so that it has `target="_blank"` or similar, removing them would complicate allowing an Unsplash search followed by a Google Images search.)

So something like this:

```
function unsplash() {
  // #1
  form.action="https://unsplash.com/search/photos/" + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
  // #2
  input.disabled = true;
  helper.disabled = true;
  helper.disabled = true;
}
```

Note the use of [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

And of course, if you did update the page so that it opened a new window instead of replacing the current window, you'd update your `googleImages` function to set `disabled` to `false` on those inputs (since it will be left `true` by the `unsplash` function). You don't have to do that if you're replacing the page, though.

Comment: but when <input type="text"> is disabled, how to get input value (search term)?

Comment: @Lucas - You said that Unslpash doesn't take query string parameters. You didn't say how it knows what to search for. How do you send it that information if not via a query string parameter, in a `form method="GET"`?

Comment: TJ, sorry for my bad english. What I tryng to say is that Google Images use some URL parameters like [google.com/search?q=lion&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=lion&tbm=isch) that I can reproduce in the form. However, Unsplash not use querystring (?) or parameters (q=value) they just use the "URL/value" [unsplash.com/search/photos/lion](https://unsplash.com/search/photos/lion) is possible reproduce this in a  HTML form? thanks :)

Comment: @Lucas - Ah, I understand now! I've updated the answer. :-)